# View with contextual filters and no value does not work

Tags: 7, views

In a view I use a contextual filters with two fields: (category, subcategory)
When I build an URL with values on both fields i.e. `/?q=gallery-details/Anciens/dessin&page=1` it works.

Idem if I give a value only on the first filter i.e. `/?q=gallery-details/Anciens&page=1`

But if I do not specify a value for the first filter and only one for the second filter, it does not work, even if it's configured to display all results when no value is specified in the URL. i.e. `/?q=gallery-details//dessin&page=1`

Do you know if there a way to do it work?